# Where to put logging setup code in a flask app?

Tags: flask, wsgi

I'm writing my first Flask application. The application itself runs fine. I just have a newbie question about logging in production mode.

The basic structure:

```
app/
app/templates/
app/static
config.py
flask/... <- virtual env with flask + extensions
run.py
```

The application is started by `run.py` script:

```
#!flask/bin/python

import os.path
import sys

appdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
if appdir not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(1, appdir)

from app import app as application

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(debug=True)
```

and is started either directly or from an Apache 2.4 web server. I have these lines in the apache config:

```
WSGIPythonHome /usr/local/opt/app1/flask
WSGIScriptAlias /app1 /usr/local/opt/app1/run.py
```

In the former case, the `debug=True` is all I need for the development.

I'd like to have some logging also for the latter case, i.e. when running under Apache on a production server. Following is a recommendation from the Flask docs:

```
if not app.debug:
    import logging
    from themodule import TheHandlerYouWant
    file_handler = TheHandlerYouWant(...)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

It needs some customization, but that's what I want - instructions for the case when `app.debug` flag is not set. Similar recommendation was given also here:
[How do I write Flask's excellent debug log message to a file in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037975/how-do-i-write-flasks-excellent-debug-log-message-to-a-file-in-production)

Please help: where do I have to put this code?

---

UPDATE: based on the comments by davidism and the first answer I've got I think the app in the current simple form is not suitable for what I was asking for. I will modify it to use different sets of configuration data as recommended here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/#development-production . If my application were larger, I would follow the pech0rin's answer.

UPDATE2: I think the key here is that the environment variables should control how the application is to be configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a lot of success with setting up my logging configurations inside a `create_app` function. This uses the [application factory pattern](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/appfactories/). This allows you to pass in some arguments or a configuration class. The application is then specifically created using your parameters.

This allows you initialize the application, setup logging, and do whatever else you want to do, before the application is sent back to be run.

For example:

```
def create_app(dev=False):
   app = Flask(__name__)
   if dev:
      app.config['DEBUG'] = True
   else:
      ...
      app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
   return app
```

This has worked very well for me in production environments. YMMV

Comment: With an application factory, I would need blueprints, wouldn't I?

Comment: @VPfB yes you would need to use blueprints, but they are very helpful for overall code structure as well as only requiring about 3 more lines of code. you just need to declare a blueprint, use the blueprint name for the route decorators instead of app, and then register the blueprint with the app in the `create_app` function.

Comment: it took me some time to think it over. Accepting your answer that the application factory is the way to go.